# Twitter/Facebook embedded posts not mobile friendly

Tags: html, facebook, mobile, twitter, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm working on an app with a card based layout. In some cards I have embedded facebook/twitter posts using Facebook's Javascript SDK and Twitter's widgets.js. On desktop the cards look fine, as I would expect (see first screenshot).

When I emulate a mobile device (E.g. iPhone 5/6, Nexus 6, etc) using the Chrome device emulator, the embedded posts are so small that they are illegible, even after reloading the page (see second screenshot).

Here is the HTML I have for one of my cards with an embedded post:

```
<div class="card result-link content result center-card no-hover" ng-class="{'mobile': $parent.isMobile}" ng-show="post.show">
    <div class="card-title">
        <i class="fa fa-signal"></i>
        <div class="title-txt">
            Amplify <i class="fa" ng-class="invite.date_submitted ? 'fa-circle-o' : 'fa-circle'"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="timestamp">
            {{post.requested_timestamp}}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div ng-if="post.provider === 'twitter'" id="{{'post_' + post.id}}"></div>

    <div id="fb_embed" ng-if="post.provider === 'facebook'">
        <div class="fb-post" data-href="{{post.facebook_link}}"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The above card is a directive. Here is the directive code:

```
app.directive('amplifyRequest', ['$http', '$timeout', function($http, $timeout) {
    return {
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: '/assets/amplify_request.html',
        transclude: false,
        scope: {
            post: '='
        },
        controller: ['$scope', '$http', '$timeout', function($scope, $http, $timeout) {    
            if($scope.post.provider === 'twitter') {
                $timeout(function() {
                    twttr.widgets.createTweet($scope.post.twitter_id, document.getElementById('post_' + $scope.post.id));
                },100)
            };
        }]
    };
}]);
```

Here is what a Twitter embed looks like on desktop:

[image]

Here is the same Tweet on a simulated iPhone 6:

[image]

What I'd like to know is what I'm doing wrong here. From what I've read in the docs and seen on other sites, the tweets/posts should automatically detect if the device is a mobile and adjust. That doesn't seem to be happening here though.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps someone in the future. I was going over the Bootstrap docs again trying to figure out what I was missing when I realized that I'm missing a critical meta tag for mobile. For what it's worth I've been using Bootstrap for over a year now, but haven't done much mobile work with it.

I popped this line into my page's `<head>` tag and now everything looks normal.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```